# Laravel Web and API login

Tags: laravel, rest, api

I'm trying to build a platform where a Supplier can login to the platform, a normal web login.

But from the outside webshops can place orders using my REST API. Each webshop should be able to place an order but how would I go about authenticating those webshops?

> Should I generate a sort of token for each webshop which they have to send in each request? Is it possible using JWT to issue a token to each shop that they will use for life? And so I know which shop is trying to create an order?

Looking very forward to your ideas.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned laravel in the topic, try [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport)

Here is a nice introduction blog post about it:

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-passport

You can have it up and running within hours, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is many package can do this including Passport as mentioned by @veNuker
my sugestion use [Api-Guard](https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard) is easy to use